# XeLaTeX Document with PSTricks does not Compile on Overleaf

Tags: pstricks, overleaf

The following code is perfectly executing in TexStudio with XeLaTeX. But not working in Overleaf. Can anybody help me to find the problem ?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \psscalebox{1.0 1.0} % Change this value to rescale the drawing.
    {
        \begin{pspicture}(0,-6.869608)(3.4228299,-3.2345715)
            \definecolor{colour0}{rgb}{0.6,0.2,0.0}
            \rput(0.36892363,-6.3424816){\psaxes[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, tickstyle=full, axesstyle=axes, labels=all, ticks=all, ticksize=0.1411111cm, dx=1.0cm, dy=1.0cm](0,0)(0,0)(3,3)}
            \psline[linecolor=black, linewidth=0.04, fillstyle=gradient, gradlines=2000, gradbegin=colour0, gradend=red](0.34892365,-5.3424816)(1.3489237,-6.3224816)(3.0289237,-6.062482)(1.2089237,-4.0024815)(0.38892365,-5.3224816)(0.38892365,-5.3224816)
        \end{pspicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? If yes, maybe post it along with the code.

Comment: Please consider making your title more meaningful to others, I propose "XeLaTeX Document with PSTricks does not Compile on Overleaf".

Comment: Use `lualatex` as compiler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works for me, I *assume* that you did not specify the **compiler** correctly, see screenshots.

[image]

[image]

FYI, this is the error message I get when I use `pdfLaTeX` as the compiler:

> ```
> \c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
>                          _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
> l.13     }
>           
> The control sequence at the end of the top line
> of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
> misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
> spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
> and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
> ```

[image]